# Is it possible to have session-like parameters on Celery?

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, celery

I have an API that send messages to an application running on Celery.

Is it possible to have session-like arguments on the Celery application?

For example: I send a message from the API and that message is received with some parameters. After receiving the message, ***I would like to set some variables that will be visible and permanent for the whole lifecycle of the message, without changing because of another message received.***

It's just like a multithread concurrency problem when we have variables assigned inside the application. These variables can change before one of the threads complete its execution flow.

Please let me know if the problem described is not clear enough.
Thanks,